# Does this language mean can print out anything on this site?

Tags: licensing, legal-terms

I encountered this language on a website that hosts preserved books in the form of PDF's. Does this mean that I can print out any of the PDF's. Assuming I'm not limited to the restrictions.

> 1. Limited License:  The Society for the... hereby grants you a limited, nonexclusive right and license, solely for your personal use, to use the Site view, download, and print the Publications, subject to the following restrictions:

Comment: Note that you need a license from *the copyright holders*.  Does the Society for X actually hold the copyright on the books that they are hosting, or been granted relicensing authority by the copyright holder?

Comment: *"subject to the following restrictions:"* what are those restrictions?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Assuming I'm not limited to the restrictions.*" please

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed. The [limited license condition](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/media/terms.html)

> hereby grants you a limited, nonexclusive right and license, solely
> for your personal use, to use the Site view, download, *and print the
> Publications*

as long as your use is not against the law, do not use it for commercial purposes, and do not resell a publication or charge a fee for its use. The wording of the license does raise a question as to whether you are allowed to use the site, download or print for purposes that are *not* solely personal, but are also not commercial. [This article](https://repository.law.umich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1218&context=articles) surveys the legally slippery territory covered by "personal use" under US copyright law.